# Calculus Question: $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan (x)\log(\sin x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can anyone help me to find  $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan (x)\log(\sin x)dx$? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally I am able using Tex

Comment: I just did it with mathematica and it returns $-\pi^2/24$. Wolfram agrees.

Comment: `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral&a=*C.Integral-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=tan%28x%29log%28sinx%29&f=Integral.integrand\u005ftan%28x%29log%28sinx%29&f3=0&f=Integral.rangestart_0&f4=pi%2F2&f=Integral.rangeend_pi%2F2&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Integral.variable---.**Integral.rangestart-.*Integral.rangeend---` apparently this integral is diverging

Comment: @user2485710 As far as I can see, Wolfram agrees with Gennaro.  Which means my answer is likely wrong.

Comment: @Mike the numerical result from Wolfram also matches that, $-\pi^{2}/24 = -0.411233516712057$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rewrite
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan x\ln(\sin x)\,dx=\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\ln(\sin x)\ dx.
\end{align}
$$
Let $\,u=\cos x$, then $\,du=-\sin x\,dx$. For $\,0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\,0 < u < 1$. Now, the integral turns out to be
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\ln(\sin x)\,dx&=\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\ln(\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x})\,dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-u^2)}{u}\,du.\tag1\\
\end{align}
$$
Next, use [Maclaurin series for natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions):
$$
\ln(1-u^2)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u^{2n}}{n}.\tag2\\
$$
Substitute $\,(2)$ to $\,(1)$, yield
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-u^2)}{u}\,du&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u^{2n}}{un}\,du\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1 \frac{u^{2n-1}}{n}\,du\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left.\frac{u^{2n}}{n^2}\right|_{u=0}^1\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.\tag3
\end{align}
$$
The infinite series in $(3)$ is defined as [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) $\,\zeta (2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan x\ln(\sin x)\,dx&=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
&=\large\color{blue}{-\frac{\pi^2}{24}}.\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: FYI, I've just seen that my answer and Cody are similar but I didn't copy his answer. I should have posted the answer 3 hours ago but my internet connection suddenly got offline. I also want to ask the OP where did he/she get this question since it's exactly the same with [this post](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/zeta2-fracpi26/?group=UyuGs0HHFdFU).

Comment: I know how that internet connection things is. I accidentally cut mine the other day while trimming :)

Comment: @Cody Yeah, that was really annoying me. It happens to all of us. :D

Comment: @Integrals Thanks Jeff. Your recent answers are also nice.

Comment: I choose your answer because it's complete solution. This question comes from my calc quiz. Thank you!

Comment: @Tunk-Fey All of my answers are nice ;).  Thank you my friend

Comment: @Integrals All of integral questions are also nice. I really enjoy it. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is one line proof using beta function

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan (x)\log(\sin x)dx=\lim_{a\rightarrow 1,b\rightarrow 1^+}\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial B}{\partial a}\left(\frac{1}{2}(a+1),\frac{1}{2}(b+1)\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$

**Q.E.D.**

Comment: Thanks. I've just realized this method from your post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1021647/146687 and apparently someone is using Tunk-Fey's method to evaluate your integral & I like that answer.

Comment: Anyway, at that time, I didn't know beta function

Comment: @Venus Welcome :-). See $(14)$ here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)log(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)}dx$$

Let $t=\cos(x), \;\ \sin(x)=\sqrt{1-t^{2}}, \;\ dx=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}dt$

$$1/2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{log(1-t^{2})}{t}dt$$

This integral can be done using the series for $$log(1-t^{2})=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2k}}{k}$$, and is rather famous.

But, it evaluates to $$\frac{-\pi^{2}}{24}$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\frac{\log t}t$?

Comment: @Mike It's correct.  There is just a typo on the first line.  It should be $\log (\sin x)$, not $\log (\cos x)$.

Answer (score 5):

Subst. $t=\sin{x}$, then the given integral becomes
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^1 \, \frac{t\, \log{t}}{1-t^2} dt &= \int_{0}^{1} \, \log{t} \, \sum_{k\ge 0} t^{2k+1} \, dt\\
&= \sum_{k\ge 0} \int_{0}^{1} \, \left(\log{t}\right)\, t^{2k+1}\, dt\\
&=  \sum_{k\ge 0} -\frac{1}{4 \, {\left(k^{2} + 2 \, k + 1\right)}}\\
&= -\frac{1}{4} \zeta{(2)}\\
&= -\frac{\pi^2}{24}
\end{align*}

In general, we can have
\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \, \left(\log{\sin{x}}\right)^n\, \tan{x}\, dx = (-1)^n\, \frac{ n!\,  \zeta(n + 1)}{2^{n + 1}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\overbrace{\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan\pars{x}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x}}
^{\ds{t\ \equiv \sin\pars{x}}}\
=\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{t\ln\pars{t} \over 1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{t\ \equiv \expo{-\xi}}}\ =\
-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\xi\expo{-2\xi} \over 1 - \expo{-2\xi}}\,\dd\xi
\\[3mm]&=
-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\xi\expo{-\xi} \over 1 - \expo{-\xi}}\,\dd\xi
=\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}\,\dd\xi
={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\expo{-n\xi} \over n}}\,\dd\xi
\\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-n\xi}\,\dd\xi}_{\ds{=\ {1 \over n}}}
=-\,{1 \over 4}\ \underbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}}
_{\ds{=\ {\pi^{2} \over 6}}} = \color{#00f}{\Large -\,{\pi^{2} \over 24}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

I just finished [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1041173) and noticed that equation $(6)$ there answers this question. I did a small amount of customization for this question.

Let $t=\sin(x)$ and $e^{-u/2}=t$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{t}{1-t^2}\log(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{1-e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac14\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty ue^{-ku}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}
\end{align}
$$
This is only slightly different from Felix Marin's answer, using the series for $\dfrac{x}{1-x}$ instead of $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Thanks for giving this answer. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ I(a,b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{1-a}(\cos x)^{1-b}dx.$$
Then 
$$ I(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{b}{2}\right)}{2
   \Gamma \left(-\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}+2\right)} $$
and hece
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial I(a,b)}{\partial a}&=&\frac{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{a}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{b}{2}\right)
   \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}+2\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)}{4 \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}+2\right)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial I(0,b)}{\partial a}&=&\frac{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{b}{2}\right) \left(\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(2-\frac{b}{2}\right)+\gamma \right)}{4 \Gamma
   \left(2-\frac{b}{2}\right)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Noting
$$ \Gamma(x)\approx\frac{1}{x} \text{ near }x=0 $$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{b\to2}\frac{\partial I(0,b)}{\partial a}&=&\lim_{b\to2}\frac{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{b}{2}\right) \left(\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(2-\frac{b}{2}\right)+\gamma \right)}{4 \Gamma
   \left(2-\frac{b}{2}\right)}\\
&=&\lim_{b\to2}\frac14 \frac{\psi^{(0)}(2-\frac{b}{2})+\gamma}{1-\frac{b}{2}}\\
&=&\lim_{b\to2}\frac14 \psi^{(1)}(2-\frac{b}{2})\\
&=&\frac{\pi^2}{24}.
\end{eqnarray}
So 
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\tan x\ln(\sin x)dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}. $$