# Integral of $\log(\sin(x)) \tan(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, logarithms

I would like to see a direct proof of the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x)) \tan(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{\pi^2}{24}.$$ I arrived at this integral while trying different ways to evaluate $\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + ...$ and found this value using the known sum $\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$ It would be better to have a direct way to evaluate this.

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792950/calculus-question-int-0-frac-pi2-tan-x-log-sin-xdx?lq=1

Comment: Under the link above, the answer by xpaul is direct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x) \tan x  \, \mathrm{d}x &= \frac1{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin^2 x ) \tan x  \, \mathrm{d}x \\ &= \frac1{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\log(\sin^2 x ) \sin x}{\cos x}  \, \mathrm{d}x \\ &= \frac1{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\log(1-\cos^2 x ) \cos x \sin x}{\cos^2 x}  \, \mathrm{d}x  \end{align}.$$

Changing variables to $u = \cos^2 x$ we get

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x) \tan x  \, \mathrm{d}x &= \frac1{4}\int_0^{1} \frac{\log(1-u)}{u}  \mathrm{d}u \end{align}.$$

Now integrate the Taylor series expansion of the integrand termwise to finish.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin x) \tan x  \, \mathrm{d}x &= -\frac1{4}\int_0^{1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{u^{k-1}}{k}  \mathrm{d}u \\ &= -\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}  \end{align}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the transformation $$\sin x=e^{-z}$$ to get $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ze^{-z} }{\sqrt{1-e^{-2z}}}dz$$ Now, expand $(1-e^{-2z})^{-1/2}$ and use the [Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) functions to evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 2):

We [*know*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals#Relation_with_the_Beta_and_Gamma_functions) that, for positive values of *a* and *b*, $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin^{2a-1}x~\cos^{2b-1}x~dx~=~\frac12~B\big(a,b\big)$,

where  *B* is the [*beta function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), implying that our original integral can be written in terms

of $~\displaystyle\lim_{b\to0}B^{(1,0)}(1,b)=-\zeta(2)=-\dfrac{\pi^2}6$, which follows from the well-known relation between

the beta and [$\Gamma$ *functions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), as well as the latter's connection to the [*digamma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), [*trigamma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function), and

[*polygamma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) functions.